# Add a key-value-entry to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

i have some trouble working with arrays in PHP. The square breaket and the array_push methode does not work as expected. And even with all my imagination i can not figure out what is wrong with my way of thinking about arrays.

This is my code:

```
$users = array();
$users['4643'] = array("key1" => "value1");
$users['4643'] = array("key2" => "value2");
print_r($users);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [4643] => Array
        (
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
```

But i expected it to would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [4643] => Array
        (
            [key1] => value1
            [key2] => value2
        )

)
```

Even with array_push() - *array_push($users['4643'], array("key2" => "value2"));* - i can not add an other array to the *$users['4643']-array* (isn't this an array? PHP says so (" *[4643] => Array* ").

Please help me. I think there is something wrong with my idea of array, but even the beginer tutorials about arrays can not help me.

Comment: Your second assignment is overwriting the first array you added.

Comment: Instead of setting, you can try appending the second array with: `$users['4643'] += array("key2" => "value2");`.

Comment: There are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second assignment is overwriting the first array you added.

Instead, set values in the array like this:

```
$users['4643'] = array();
$users['4643']["key1"] = "value1";
$users['4643']["key2"] = "value2";
```

Comment: Perfect, works even without the $users['4643'] = array();
But why is array_push not working, does it only works with a numeric index